# Azure web app Remote debugging do not attach debugger and stop loading

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, debugging, azure-webapps

I have an "Asp.net Core" project published on Azure Web App.
and I'm trying to debug it remotely with visual studio 2019.
and I followed the instruction carefully me allow remote debugging in Web App..etc.
but when I started attaching the debugger, it still loading for hours without engine as follows:

[image]

I tried to find a solution but I didn't find anything to solve my problem!
i find this one but also didn't work: [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/remote-debugger-will-not-attach-to-azure-app-servi/1102218)

any idea how to solve this problem and make it work?
and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you logged in to your Azure account in Visual Studio (go to Tools->Options->Azure Service Authentication) ?

Comment: thank you, yes ofcourse i'm loged in!